# Laravel 5 - generic document management

Tags: laravel-5

I have a system where you can create different types of unique documents.  For instance, one document is called Project Identified and this expects certain inputs.  Originally, I had a database table for each unique document type, but this was getting messy fast. So, I created a database structure that was more generic, and came up with the following
[image: Database design]

So, I create a project.  Within the projects show page, I can select the type of document I want to create e.g.

```
<li>{!! link_to_route('projects.documents.create', 'Project Identified', array($project->id, 'documentType' => 'projectIdentified')) !!}</li>
```

Now if I select to create a Project Identified document, it uses the generic Document Controller to handle things.  Because the link to route has a documentType param, I can grab the value of this from the url.  As such, in my Document Controllers create function, I am doing the following to display the correct view for the document

```
public function create(Project $project)
{
    $documentType = $_GET["documentType"];

    if($documentType == "projectIdentified") {
        return View::make('projectIdentifiedDoc.create', compact('project'));
    }
}
```

This view has a form which is binded

```
{!! Form::model(new App\Document, [
    'class'=>'form-horizontal',
    'route' => ['projects.documents.store', $project->id]
]) !!}
```

However, within the document controllers store function, I once again need to get the documentType.  How can I pass this within the forms model?  Also, is this the correct way to do this or is there a more efficient way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation on relationships?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

You need to define the relationship within your model.

So if a document only has one documentType, within your document model, you would define

```
public function documentType()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\documentType');
}
```

The different types of relationship, how to define them, and then how to access that data, is all very well documented.